# Maintain State using PHP session

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-state

PHP can't maintain the state  lets say the variables initialize in one process will be lost if the page gets reload  i was reading the some of the answers  on  Stack over flow but unfortunately i couldn't get much out of them , what i know is in order to maintain the state i need to use Session   i have very simple script for learning how session works

**index.php**

```
 <?php 
if ( !isset($_SESSION['id']) ){
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = 1;
echo "Session started at index.php and id is =";
echo $_SESSION['id'];
}
 else {
++$_SESSION['id'];
echo "The session id is  : ".$_SESSION['id'];
}
?>
 <br>
 <a href="index.php">Index.php</a>
```

But whenever i reload the Page i get the following message

```
  **Session started at index.php and id is =1**
```

Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong  how can i maintain state using Sessions?
what i eventually want to do is store a object in Session variable on every post i want to append data in a instance variable (array) of that object

Comment: When dealing with sessions you must always put "`session_start()`" first... then you can do the `isset` test. I.e. reverse your first two lines of code and it should work as expected.

Comment: Actually you can use 'if (!$_SESSION) { session_start() }' as a legitimate test, though hopefully you control the flow of the site and already know if there's a session.

Comment: Oo, didn't know that! Learnt something new there... Thanks Silvertiger

Comment: See my answer below .. it should hlep

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on the first load you are checking for a session, which by default does not exist until you start one, and then subsequently starting a session and setting the ID to 1.  from that point beyond it will be "1". Also .. you need a session start each time you load so you will need in the IF and the ELSE.

```
<?php 
if (!$_SESSION){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = 1;
    echo "Session has been initiated at index.php and id is =". $_SESSION['id'];
} else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id']++;
    echo "The session id is  : ".$_SESSION['id'];
}
?>
<br>
<a href="index.php">Index.php</a>
```

Now for some reason.. if you had a previous session and linked to index the ID would still increment and not be "reset" by hitting index.

to inject submitted form variables into your session, just set the variables manually:

```
<?PHP
    if (isset($_POST['myVariable']) && !empty($_POST['myVariable'])) {
        $_SESSION['myVariable'] = $_POST['myVariable'];
    }
?>
```

but each time you submit the form with the same variables, they will be overwritten

Comment: Thanks Silvertiger  can you please tell me  how can i maintain the state of an object using session what i want to do is whenever a form gets post to the file  the data gets append to instance variable  can you please tell me how can i do that?

Comment: Thank you  and I have changed the code but session should be destroyed as soon as i close the browser right?   but i restarted my browser and it still increments the value to the last previous value

Comment: are you closing the browser, or just a tab in the browser?

Comment: Session is not necessarily destroyed when you leave the browser, it depends on the browser. Typically I develop with Google Chrome, and use Incognito mode, which creates a session that is destroyed when the browser is closed for exactly this reason, but Chrome without Incognito will keep the session for a set time before it expires.

Comment: Make sure to sanitize POST data before working with it, too, to prevent script injection attacks into your code.

Comment: Yes  you are right i am using Chrome and session stays alive but i have tested on firefox and  session gets destroyed on closing the browser

Comment: Thank you Mark yes i do always sanitize POST data  but for now i am just  testing "Maintaing State" not doing anything with database

Comment: @Silvertiger Regarding your update to the answer you said it will over ride the  previous data  but what i want to do is when use hit submit the values get append to an array not over ride them is this possible?

Comment: If you're using Chrome, use ctrl+shift+N to open up an incognito mode window, it will 100% destroy the session when ALL incognito mode windows are closed. This is especially useful because you can keep your Chrome 'normal'mode window open with Stack Overflow, without losing your login and session, but kill the Incognito mode window to do session variable testing.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
session_start();
```

under

```
<?php
```

you need to declare the session before referencing it

As you can see from your code you are saying if isn't set, well its not going to know as you haven't started the session.

Comment: well i have changed the code  but now it doesn't destroy the session even if the browsers closes

Comment: sessions dont always destory when you close the browser, check your php.ini file for 'session.cookie_lifetime' and see how long the lifetime of your session is

Comment: infact try adding session_set_cookie_params(0); above session_start();